# How to transform vue js html page into pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, pdf

i was wondering if some of you experienced this problem, to generate pdf file from vue js or other js framework pdf file. I am not going to mention what libraries i tried, i am searching for a native way. Did some of you do something closer to this. The pdf needs to be generated from page that is is dropdowns and butons, so the functionality needs to remain in some way. Can you give me some proposals how to do it, with DOM or etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you want to transform it into a pdf? On the server or in the browser?

In the browser, I'd recommend to simply allow the users to print it and use css to control what will be shown (using the `print` media query).
Then, instead of sending it to a printer, users can also choose to transform it into a pdf.

On the server you'll have to look for some libraries that offer this specific functionality and see which ones fit your usecase best.

Lastly, what do you mean with "the functionality needs to remain in some way"?
I'm not an expert in what PDFs can do, but they definitely cannot do enough to emulate a web-page – especially one that is complex enough to warrant using vue.js.
What exactly would you like to keep/have happen?

Comment: i expect it to to to generate all the variants, but i think there i library should be use. By variants i mean the menu opened here, the link to be working. For example, button which is moving you to other menu of this page to work, but thank you, i think the printing should do the work because the other is too big functionality. Do you know how i can s`ve the page as pdf like you said with button click. Without the user to need to go click print than save as pdf, to make it easier for him. Thank you again:)

Comment: `window.print()` will print the entire site from js. Probably, you'll still need to first have user interaction for browsers to allow the call. E.g. call it when a user presses a button. Having pdfs be interactive would make them giant as you'd need to basically copy every possible state that the site could be in and link in between the specific pages for it. Don't think that a pdf can have any states except for input fields, but then again, I could be wrong.